# How can I render bootstrap toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, templates, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `bootstrap` toggle in handlebars template, while page loading time perfectly it's visible but after retemplating the handlebars template(which template have toggle) it's not visible.

Before Re-Template:

[image: Before Re-Template]

code :

```
 <div class="switch switch-square has-switch" data-on-label="&lt;i class='fui-check'&gt;&lt;/i&gt;" data-off-label="&lt;i class='fui-cross'&gt;&lt;/i&gt;"><div class="switch-animate switch-off"><input type="checkbox" id="colorBar-Toggle"><span class="switch-left"><i class="fui-check"></i></span><label for="colorBar-Toggle">&nbsp;</label><span class="switch-right"><i class="fui-cross"></i></span></div></div>
```

After Re-Template:

[image]

after Re-Template code:

```
 <div class="switch switch-square" data-on-label="&lt;i class='fui-check'&gt;&lt;/i&gt;" data-off-label="&lt;i class='fui-cross'&gt;&lt;/i&gt;"><input type="checkbox" id="colorBar-Toggle"></div>
```

handleBars code:

```
      <script id="planner-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">

    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="table table-bordered table-responsive" id="joy_fifth" data-intro="5. You are now ready to play   with the planner!" data-position="top">  
      <thead>
            <tr>    
                <th width="20%">Bizstep</td>
                <th width="20%">Location</td>
                <th width="15%">Time Duration</td>
                <th width="15%">Temperature</td>
                <th width="15%">Freshtime Points</td>
                <th width="15%"><div class="switch switch-square" data-on-label="<i class='fui-check'></i>" data-off-label="<i class='fui-cross'></i>"><input type="checkbox" id="colorBar-Toggle"/></div></td>
            </tr>
         </thead>
             <tbody>...</tbody>
      </script>
```

please can anyone help me it's very importent for me.

Comment: Where is the handlebars code?  The markup is noticeably different...

Comment: @Nix I added handlebars code, can you help me.I am new to this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys I founded after re-templating if I call the following function it's working fine.But after calling function other toggle's also effecting.I found the following function in `bootstrap-switch.js` file.

I don't know why other toggle's are effecting.around other toggle's one more new `div` are adding. becuase of that I am getting extra padding around main toggle.

other toggle's code :

```
<div class="switch switch-square has-switch" data-on-label="2" data-off-label="1"><div class="switch-animate switch-off switch-on"><div class="switch-animate"><div class="switch-on switch-animate"><div class="switch-animate"><div class="switch-animate"><div class="switch-animate"><div class="switch-animate"><input type="checkbox" id="qtenToggle"><span class="switch-left">2</span><label for="qtenToggle">&nbsp;</label><span class="switch-right">1</span></div><span class="switch-left">2</span><label for="qtenToggle">&nbsp;</label><span class="switch-right">1</span></div><span class="switch-left">2</span><label for="qtenToggle">&nbsp;</label><span class="switch-right">1</span></div><span class="switch-left">2</span><label for="qtenToggle">&nbsp;</label><span class="switch-right">1</span></div><span class="switch-left">2</span><label for="qtenToggle">&nbsp;</label><span class="switch-right">1</span></div><span class="switch-left">2</span><label for="qtenToggle">&nbsp;</label><span class="switch-right">1</span></div><span class="switch-left">2</span><label for="qtenToggle">&nbsp;</label><span class="switch-right">1</span></div></div>
```

bootstrap function :

```
 $('.switch')['bootstrapSwitch']();
```